# How can i display the data in my database located in my assets folder and view it VIA ListView

Tags: android

Im making a Dictionary App for my subject and my plan is to view the content of `My Data.db` using `ListView`.

I've read [this blog about using sqlite in android](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) but I'm "NEW" in android programming.  :(

Comment: The post you're referencing to is pretty helpful, what's you question then?

Comment: Article with 568 Comments, it shows the importance and usefulness of article. Still you are having question. Something strange !!

Comment: yeah im having  a bad time understanding...  my plan is to display the data in the "Word" and "Definition" field in my "My Data.db" located in my assets folder and view it VIA ListView in my App :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article link sort of answers your question. It shows how to copy a db from your local assets folder into the db your application uses. Android is set up to create databases for you, as such it keeps them in its own file path location. Lots of tutorials show how to copy a db from your assets folder to the Application DB. This tends to be a one of installation/setup procedure after which you'd use the content provider to store data in the default location used by android.

I.e. you might provide the user with a reset option, that would carry this out, wiping existing db but replacing it with a valid empty db.

The following article looked up on google goes into some depth to that would give you further help using content providers and list. You might have to combine it with the tutorial you already have if it doesn't cover loading a db from the assets folder.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html